# How do I deploy a custom aggregation strategy in JBoss Fuse 6.1

Tags: apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fabric8

So I have an aggregation strategy class that I want to use with Multicast in Camel. I am not sure where to put this in JBoss Fuse. Currently I am using a blueprint camel.xml in a new Fabric Profile to deploy a camel route. I understand how to create an aggregation strategy, I am just not sure where to put it.

I tried doing it the old servicemix way by dropping the jar into the /deploy directory (knowing this wasn't the best way to do it) but that didn't work anyway. I am very unfamiliar with Maven. I would prefer to keep it with Fuse 6.1's new Fabric "Profiles" that are in a Git repo. I understand that may not be possible, but where would I put it if that isn't possible?

The procedure woud be the same as adding any bean to the system, but I never see where to put it in the documentation. Just how to construct it and reference it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the aggregation strategy into your application bundle, and edit the profile to add this bundle.